# Fetch value from readonly input field - Angular

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

My intention is to fetch data from a readonly input field. I have a selection of packages which dynamically changes the input field which is readonly. By that I know what package the user has chosen on submit. However, when I log ngForm the value of the input field for "Packages" stays empty.

So far my approach was to set the value of the field via property binding according to what the user has chosen.

```
<form class="w-50 mb-5 mt-5" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ngModel required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Future Family Name" ngModel required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" ngModel required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="package" value="{{selectedPackage}}" placeholder="{{selectedPackage}}" class="form-control" readonly ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" name="date" value="" placeholder="When is your wedding?" class="form-control" ngModel required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="text" rows="4" placeholder="Your message.." ngModel></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**Typescript:**

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() selectedDiv: number;
  selectedPackage: string;

  onSubmit(form: NgForm): void {
    console.log(form);
  }

  changePackageInfo(): void {
    if (this.selectedDiv === 0) {
      this.selectedPackage = 'Please choose a package from the selection above!';
    }
    if (this.selectedDiv === 1) {
      this.selectedPackage = 'You\'ve chosen Package One';
    }
    if (this.selectedDiv === 2) {
      this.selectedPackage = 'You\'ve chosen Package Two';
    }
    if (this.selectedDiv === 3) {
      this.selectedPackage = 'You\'ve chosen Package Three';
    }
  }

  public ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if ('selectedDiv' in changes) {
      this.changePackageInfo();
      }
    }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changePackageInfo();
  }

}
```

Edit: 
Is there any way to fetch the data from property binding?

Comment: use banana in the box: `<input type="text" name="package" class="form-control" readonly [(ngModel)]="selectedPackage">`

Comment: @AJT_82 That's it. Thank you again!